# Output of score function for model in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to evaluate the performance of a model and I can't seem to grasp what score is actually returning. The documentation says:

```
Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.
In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy which is a harsh 
metric since you require for each sample that each label set be correctly predicted.
```

This isn't intuitive - what is accuracy here? I'd like to see values of mean squared error to check the model. So if my model has an MSE of 30%, does this mean its "score" is 70%? If I run the a model that chooses parameters by cross validation with the scoring function set to `mean_squared_error` will this "score" be calculated based on that?

I can't seem to find any documentation on this - and I would really appreciate the help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) is the percentage of examples correctly classified.

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
>>> y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 3]
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
0.5
```

Here you have 2 examples out of 4 classified correctly, so the accuracy is 2/4 = 0.5

If you're using the **[mean_squared_error](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)** then your problem is a regression problem. Using this metric in your *[GridSearch](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html)* will find the lowest error.

The trick is, when doing gridsearch cross-validation the goal is to maximize the score function. But maximizing the error will be a bad idea, so to be consistent with sklearn API, they take the opposite of your error as the score. By doing so you maximize your score by minimizing the error.

So if you want to display your error, make sure that you take the absolute value of the score

```
>>> abs(grid_search.best_score_)
3.2
```